# Convert Spark Dataframes each row as a String with a delimiter between each column value in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I want to convert Spark Dataframe each row as a String with a delimiter between each column value.

For example:
I have a input dataframe 'df' with 3 columns "firstname","lastname","age", with two records which look like below.

Row1: John  Abhraham 21
Row2: Steve Austin   22

I want to create a new dataframe with just one column which has data like below.
Row1: John$Abhraham$21
Row2: Steve$Austin$22

Can anyone please help in doing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have a Spark shell handy, but I think this one liner should do it:

```
def stringifyRows(df: DataFrame, sep: String): DataFrame 
  = df.map(row => row.mkString(sep)).toDf("myColumnName")
```

For your example, you would call this as `stringifyRows(myDf, "$")`. Let me know what the error message is if this doesn't work.

Comment: Yes I have used your code. Since the return type of the function is Dataframe, I had to use .toDF() after `row.mkString(sep)).toDF()`

Comment: but the new dataframe that is created is having the column name  as "_1". How do i give the name for the column here.

Comment: Your code is working correctly, thanks for it. But how do i give the column name for it.

Comment: I know I can use .withColumn, and rename the column, but is there any way that I can give the column name while calling the function stringifyRows itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `concat` for this.

For example:

```
df.select(concat($"firstname", lit("$"), $"lastname", lit("$"), "age")).show()
```

OR

```
df.withColumn("newColumnName",concat($"firstname", lit("$"), $"lastname", lit("$"), "age")).show()
```

Comment: Doesn't this not work for an arbitrary number of columns?

Comment: @Alec: Yes i agree, your answer is the correct one for arbitraray number of columns...  +1

Comment: @Shankar, Yes I actually have more columns to work with, so I think I have to go with other approach.